# TinkerPop3 updating graph during traversal

Tags: java, traversal, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'm using a TinkerPop3 Traversal in Java, and I want to update output vertices, edit them and then have that edited vertex not show up again while the traversal continues. Is this possible?

This code:

```
TinkerGraph tg = TinkerGraph.open();

/**add some vertices and edges**/

GraphTraversalSource gt = tg.traversal();
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<String,Object>> traversal = gt.V()
    .has("processed",false).as("initial")
    .out()
    .aggregate("vertices")
    .select("initial","vertices");

while(traversal.hasNext()){
    initial.property("processed",true);
}
```

Will repeatedly spit out the first vertex that it finds over and over, even though I have set the "processed" property to true.

What can I do to fix or work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on in your code example, but if you want to set properties within a traversal, you can do so in a single line of code.  See my console session:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> graph.addVertex('processed',false)
==>v[0]
gremlin> graph.addVertex('processed',false)
==>v[2]
gremlin> graph.addVertex('processed',false)
==>v[4]
gremlin> graph.addVertex('processed',true)
==>v[6]
gremlin> g.V().has('processed',false)
==>v[0]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.V().has('processed',false).property('processed',true)
==>v[0]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.V().has('processed',false)
gremlin>
```

You can see that all "processed" properties are now set to `false`.

Comment: Ugghhh, of course. It also turns out that re-initializing the traversal will have it pick up any changes that you made to the vertices in java.